# WinDev Print " character

Tags: windev

Hi I want to print an HTML document with my WindevMobile 21 (Android) app but I have a problem with the caracter ", I tried to write """" but it prints "".

An example:

```
fSaveText("myHtml.html","<td align=""""right"""" colspan=""""7"""">")
```

Result `<td align=""right"" colspan=""7"">` instead of  `<td align="right" colspan="7">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works changing """" by ""

```
fSaveText("myHtml.html","<td align=""right"" colspan=""7"">")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions :

1)

```
fSaveText("myHtml.html","<td align="+Charact(34)+"right"+Charact(34)+" colspan="+Charact(34)+"7"+Charact(34)+">")
```

2)

```
ContentHTML is string=[
<td align="right" colspan="7">
]
fSaveText("myHtml.html",ContentHTML )
```